# check if a function exists in typescript

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic2

I am converting js code to typescript (angular 1 to 2)...painful operation!

the line below `if (_usersDatabase.updateReplication == null) {` leads to a Typescript error:

```
Typescript Error
Property 'updateReplication' does not exist on type 'Database<{}>'.
```

. It's made to check if the function is already defined.

How can I write this for Typescript please ?

```
import { MigrationService } from '../providers/migration-service';
import { CouchConstants } from '../couch-constants';
import * as PouchDB from 'pouchdb';

@Injectable()
export class UsersDatabase {

    constructor(
        private storageService: LocalStorageService
        , private UtilsService: UtilsService
        , private MigrationService: MigrationService

    ) {

    'use strict';

    var _usersDatabase = new PouchDB(CouchConstants.COUCHDB_USERS_DB_NAME);

    if (_usersDatabase.updateReplication == null) {

        _usersDatabase.updateReplication = function (newDocsIds) {
```

Comment: what's wrong with what you did?

Comment: I get an error (edited the question)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- no need to use `'use strict';` in typescript File
- access their method and variables using `this`.

  ```
  @Injectable()
  export class UsersDatabase {
  private _usersDatabase : any;

  constructor(
      private storageService: LocalStorageService
      , private UtilsService: UtilsService
      , private MigrationService: MigrationService

  ) {

  this._usersDatabase = new PouchDB(CouchConstants.COUCHDB_USERS_DB_NAME);

  if (this._usersDatabase.updateReplication == null) {

          this._usersDatabase.updateReplication = function (newDocsIds) {

          }
   }
  }
  ```

Comment: but `var` is also fine with Typescript.

Comment: yes `var` is fine, i have not mention anywhere that var is not fair with typescript.

Comment: No actually I still have the same error: `Typescript Error
Property 'updateReplication' does not exist on type 'Database<{}>'.
src/providers/users-database.ts
  if (this._usersDatabase.updateReplication == null) {`

Comment: I removed 'use strict', and added the declaration with `private .... ` and added `this.`, but actually I still have the same error: `Typescript Error
Property 'updateReplication' does not exist on type 'Database<{}>'.
src/providers/users-database.ts
  if (this._usersDatabase.updateReplication == null) {`

Comment: showing error because property of type `updateReplication` doest not exist on `_usersDatabase`, try chnages like
`private _usersDatabase : any;`

Comment: ok now there's no more error. So I am edited your answer, is that ok ?

Comment: yeah sure, great

Comment: in the spirit of your changes, if I have to use usersDatabase nested inside functions, should I use this.this ? (I am gonna edit your response with an example.)  i.e. `this._usersDatabase.updateReplication = function (newDocsIds) { 
this.this._usersDatabase.destroy().then(function () {
     this.this.this._usersDatabase = pouchDB(CouchConstants.COUCHDB_USERS_DB_NAME);`

Comment: maybe it's best if I ask this in another question